# Are reflection and transmission coefficents real or complex?

Tags: waves, scattering, reflection

Is it common practice to give [reflection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_coefficient) and [transmission coefficients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_coefficient) as the ratio of the respective waves with respect to the incident wave when written in complex form or real form? I have seen both so is it just a matter of preference?

Comment: It depends on the phase shift.

Comment: @jinawee how? If we have no phase shift then the real and complex versions are the same but if we do, we still have the question of which to use / state the real or complex version?

Comment: What do you mean by real or complex version? The reals are a subset of complex numbers, so if I say $r=2$, would you say it's real or complex?

Comment: @jinawee By complex I mean the ratio of $A$ and $A_r$ when the (say) the  incedent wave and reflected wave are written in the form $y=Ae^{i(\omega t-kx)}$ & $y=A_r e^{i(\omega t+kx)}$ respectfuly and real the ratio when they are written in the form $y=Acos(\omega t-kx)$ and $y=A_r cos(\omega t+kx)$ respectfuly

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Amplitude* coefficients are complex.   The reflection and transmission coefficients must account for both amplitude change and phase change.    In order to account for both of these, complex coefficients are required.  These are the most general, and are needed for a complete description.

In some special (and simple) cases, the phase shift is $0^\circ$ or $180^\circ$, and the coefficient may be expressed as a positive real or negative real.  An example would be an ideal mirror.

There might be times when all that is needed is the amplitude is needed, so the phase can be dropped.  (I'm not sure when one would use such a thing.)

If one is interested in *intensity* or *power* coefficients, the appropriate coefficient is the modulus of the amplitude coefficient, and hence is a positive definite number.

**Edit**  In the last paragraph I really should say *the square* of the modulus

Comment: Don't you mean the square of the modulus?

Comment: @BrianBi Yes, to be completely clear.  will edit, THanks.